# Why do almost all of our refering sites produce the same number of references?

Tags: discussion

[image]

Except for the top site all others show exactly 415 references. Likely I am just misunderstanding what I am seeing. I would have expected linguistics stackexchange to refer back to us way more often than space.stackexchange.

Answer (score 5):

Because the data comes from a sample, as explained in [Analytics search keywords are unreliable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121423/analytics-search-keywords-are-unreliable)

In practical terms this means the number of referrals is too low to be determined with any reasonable accuracy.